# Elasticsearch for Audit trail

Tags: elasticsearch, audit

I wanted to know whether elasticsearch is a good option for audit logs. I have a web application which uses Oracle Database. For each action on the tables, we are maintaining audit trail. We need to have a dedicated reporting tool for generating audit reports. For that purpose, is it good to load the audit data into elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can migrate your data from Oracle database to elastic search.

You can keep the data at both the place Oracle database as well as elastic search.

For reporting, you can also use tool from elk stack called as kibana. Kibana with fetch the data from elastic search and you can create the report in the kibana.

Here you can also archive the older audit trail data in the elastic search. You can apply the index management policy for the same.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have one more question. Is elasticsearch a good option to store data that is like 5 years or 10 years old?

Comment: Yes... elastic search is a good option to store the old data as well